# Trying to get multiple <span> elements by classname and change their value to true or false

Tags: javascript, html, boolean, element

I've just about tried this every possible way, I'm super new at this.

I'm trying to get the element using class name, and then I'm trying to change it's value to true so that I can run a function I made that uses .push and an if/else statement to build a new array based off of the values in the spans (I'll post that function at the bottom)

Any help anyone can provide would be awesome, I've been at this for the last 3 evenings and I'm just stuck and I have to have this solved by tomorrow.. :(

A billion thanks in advance!

JavaScript

```
// Function Declaration to check the user's character choice.
function userChoiceCheck(uChoice, low) {
    for (var j = 0; j < low.length; j++) {
        if (uChoice == low[j]) {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(low[j]);
            element.setAttribute = "true";
             console.log(element);
             console.log("The value of " + low[j] + " should now be true!");
        } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName(low[j].class).value = "false";
            console.log("The value of " + low[j] + " should now be false!");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="text-center pt-5">
    <h1 id="wordGuessArea">
    <span class="m" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="o" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="o" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="s" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="e" value="false">__ </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

function mentioned above:

```
// Function Declaration to merge censoredWord Array and upper Array into a 
new array called displayArr. Depending on the boolean value of the span that 
contains the character.
function mergeArr(low, up, wSplit, cWord) {
    for (var m = 0; m < wSplit.length; m++) {
        var targetCharSpan = document.getElementsByClassName(low[m]);
        var charSpanVal = targetCharSpan.value;
        if (charSpanVal == true) {
            displayArr.push(up[m]);
        } else if (charSpanVal == false) {
            displayArr.push(cWord[m]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, not a single Element - even if there's only one "match" - you need to iterate through this collection (for loop for example) - alternatively, if you know there will only ever be one of any class - you can use `document.querySelector`

Comment: I did this --> console.log(document.getElementsByName(low[j]));

and I get this --> NodeList [span]

Can you not use bool values in a span? So confused @_@

Comment: huh? it's a NodeList, which also isn't an element

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are having trouble on get all element by class,

if so, you need a loop

`getElementsByClassName` return a <s>array</s> HTMCollection, instead of using `element.setAttribute`, you should loop through every element inside your `element` variable

Like this:

```
for(let i=0;i<element.length;i++)
{
   element[i].setAttribute = "true";
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a HTMCollection not an Array.
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem this way using jQuery

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="text-center pt-5">
    <h1 id="wordGuessArea">
    <span class="m" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="o" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="o" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="s" value="false">__ </span>
    <span class="e" value="false">__ </span>
    </h1>
</div>

<script>

for(var i=0;i<$('#wordGuessArea span').length;i++){
   //Applying for all span elements inside wordGuessArea id

   $('#wordGuessArea span').html('Bla'); 

}
</script>

</body>
```